# chart.JS i want to put different color for each Y axis value grid line color

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, chart.js, react-chartjs

I am using MVC 4.0 and chart.JS to generate my graph. I want to put Horizontal line of Y axis for each value and I get success to develop it by using below property.

```
scaleShowGridLines = true;
scaleShowHorizontalLines: true,
//Boolean - Whether to show vertical lines (except Y axis)
scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
```

But my actual requirement is that I want to put different color of Horizontal line.

```
scaleGridLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.05)"
```

Above line change color of horizontal line but its apply for all line.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 2):

You can change each individual line on the Y-axis by adding a color array to gridLines.

```
options={{
     scales: {
         yAxes: [{
             gridLines: {
                  color: ['rgba(36, 206, 0, 0.8)', 'rgba(255, 255, 0, .8)','rgba(255, 162, 0, 0.8)','rgba(36, 206, 0, 0.8)'],
             }
          }],
      },
 }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set individual colors for the horizontal and vertical gridlines by adding a `scales` configuration to your `options`:

```
scales: {
    yAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
            color: 'green'
        }
    }],
    xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
            color: 'red'
        }  
    }]
}
```

Comment: My actual requirement is i want to change each Y axis line color. I mean on Y axis i have value from 0 ,10,20,30 then i need to show 0 as green , 10 as yellow , 20 as orange,30 as green Lines.